# Is there a proof that this polynomial solvable by radicals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, solvable-groups

If $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $t$, a constructible number, over $\mathbb{Q}$, then is $f(x)$ solvable by radicals?

It seems to be true, at least with the examples I came up with. Can it be proved though?

Comment: Is $\sqrt[3]2$ a constructible number to you?

Comment: If by *constructible* you mean *ruler+compass constructible*, then the answer is *Yes*. The number $t$ will belong to a tower of fields where each link is gotten from the previous by adjoining a square root.

Comment: No, the cubic root of 2 is NOT a constructible number!

Comment: @E.Girgin Constructible in the usual sense (the definition in every textbook)! :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the algebraic characterization of a constructible number $t$ is that there exists a sequence of field extensions $F_0=\mathbb Q, F_1,\ldots, F_n$ such that $ [F_i:F_{i-1}]=2$ and $t\in F_n$. 
This can be easily proved starting from the geometric definition of constructibility, considering that the elementary ruler and compass operations correspond, from the point of view of the analytical geometry, to solving quadratic equations.
The fact that  $ [F_i:F_{i-1}]=2$ implies that any $x\in F_{i} $ can be expressed in terms of square roots of elements in $F_{i-i}$. In particular $t$ is a combination of radicals of radicals ... of the rational numbers.

Comment: But how does this show that $f(x)$ is solvable by radicals? How do I know what its other roots are (and that its splitting field is contained in a radical extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: If an irreducible  polynomial has a root in a given extension, has all roots in that extension.

Comment: @guestDiego So, all the roots of $x^3-2$ lie in $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]2]$? Your claim is wrong.

Comment: Yes, the formulation is wrong! Thank you. I had to assume that the extension had to be the splitting field of a polynomial on $\mathbb Q$. But in that case I am not sure it is. I need to think more about that.